# Updating indices after removal

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently populating a table with help of a list, the elements selected are inserted into a seperate table, where they are assigned a slider and a id. The problem is when I start removing items from the select, the ids has be coherent (1,2,3,4 etc). Is there a way to update the ids without removing everything and starting over?

I use the following code to update it now:

```
    for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
        var row = table.rows[i]
        var id = row.cells[1].querySelector(".rs-range").id;
        var $el = $("#" + id)attr("name", "Skill[" + (i - 1) + "]");
```

This seems like a inefficient way to do it. This has to run each time I update the selection, just to ensure that they are all in the correct order.

Comment: can you please add some sample code to your question?

Comment: Which part of it? The entire thing?

Comment: the code in order to see/reproduce your issue